# Classcast exception hibernate mapping nvarchar

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am trying to use DetachedCriteria to retreive Database details from the SQl server DB like below. the nvarcharID is of String Type

```
List<POJO> pojoObj = (List<POJO>) getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(DetachedCriteria.forClass(
            POJO.class).add(Restrictions.idEq(nvarcharID)));
```

In My POJO I have following attributes

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "ID")
private double ID;

@Nationalized
@Column(name = "Column1")
private String string1;

@Nationalized
@Column(name = "column2")
private String string2;
```

Both column1 and column 2 are of type nvarchar inSql serverDB. and nvarcharID used above in the Criteria is another field in DB which is of type nvarchar in DB and I have mapped it as String. While populating the POJO, I do not want navarcharID field to be part of my POJO.

For hibernate I have following dependencies in my gradle file

```
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '4.3.11.Final'
compile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '1.0.0.GA'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator-annotation-processor', version: '4.3.2.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '4.3.2.Final'
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.11.Final'
```

and my Spring dependencies are

```
 compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version:'4.1.6.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '4.1.6.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-web', version: '4.0.2.RELEASE'
```

I am also setting following properties in my Hibernate config file for Dialect and ddl operations.

```
   @Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    localSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.wk.cdi" });

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.use_nationalized_character_data", "true");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    localSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(properties);
    return localSessionFactoryBean;
}
```

**When I try to use hibernateTemplate to retreive the data I am getting
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double and it throws the error while using DetachedCriteria ealborated above**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PLease ignore this as there was something else.
It happens to be that the Restrcition.idEq needed to be replaced by Restrictions.eq